# Odd behaviour dynamically generated linearLayouts and imageView to a custom cell adapter

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to generate a list View "facebook" style, with custom cells and different information on each cell, everything is working as it should, but the thumbnail image gallery is reacting very odd.

the gallery does not appear at first, but when I scroll down it appears in the wrong cell and once I scroll up or down again it just keep showing randomly in the wrong cells and it start to double on one of the cells (shows 2, then 4, then 6...)

For that I am dynamically adding linear layouts(horizontal) into a previous generated linear layout(vertical), and generating image views as needed and making the thumbnails clickeables in order to show the full size picture as tapped.

the code for dynamically generating the thumbnails is working fine and is tested on another class that I also use it, but when trying to use it inside my adapter for the custom cell is not showing me the images.

the code for the thumbnails is the follow:

```
                   if(!numPics.equals("0")){
                        imageGallery(gT, userId, trainingId);
                    }
```

and the code for the "imageGallery" void is the follow:

```
void imageGallery (LinearLayout gT, String userId, String trainingId){

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("trainingid" ,trainingId));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", userId));

        String url = Common.thumbnail();
        String strPic = Common.doPost(url, nameValuePair);
        String fullImUrl = Common.fullImage();
        String fullImValue = Common.doPost(fullImUrl, nameValuePair);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        try{
            boolean fFlg2 = true;
            final String[] arrayFile;

            int startIdx1 = 0;
            int endIdx1 = 0;
            int startIdx2 = 0;
            int endIdx2 = 0;


            endIdx1 = fullImValue.indexOf(",", startIdx1);
            endIdx2 = strPic.indexOf(",",startIdx2);
            int ImageNum = Integer.valueOf(fullImValue.substring(startIdx1,endIdx1));
            int ImageNum2 = Integer.valueOf(strPic.substring(startIdx2,endIdx2));
            Log.d("string", "" + ImageNum2);
            String fileNames = fullImValue.substring(endIdx1+1);
            arrayFile = new String[ImageNum];

            String fileNames2 = strPic.substring(endIdx2+1);
            String strUrl2 = Common.server;

            int niv = 0;
            int nivrow = 0;


            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(FriendsDiaries.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            boolean rowFlg = true;
            boolean row1Flg = true;

            for (int i=0; i< ImageNum2; i++){
                endIdx1 = fileNames.indexOf(",",startIdx1);
                endIdx2 = fileNames2.indexOf(",",startIdx2);
                String fileName = fileNames.substring(startIdx1,endIdx1);
                String thumUrl = strUrl2 + fileNames2.substring(startIdx2,endIdx2);
                arrayFile[i] = fileName;
                startIdx1 = endIdx1+1;

                ImageView iv = new ImageView(FriendsDiaries.this);

                Bitmap bmImg = null;
                URL myFileUrl =null; 

                try {
                 myFileUrl= new URL(thumUrl);
                 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 }

                 try {
                 HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
                 conn.setDoInput(true);
                 conn.connect();
                 InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                 bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                 final int position2 = niv;
                 niv++;

                 final int selectNum = position2;
                 iv.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
                 iv.setId(i+1);
                 final int id_ = iv.getId();
                 Log.e("a1", ""+ id_);
                 iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                     public void onClick(View v){

                         handler.post(new Runnable(){
                                public void run(){
                                    moveScreen(arrayFile, selectNum);
                                }
                            });
                     }

                 });
                 nivrow++;
                 if(ImageNum2 > 4){
                     if(row1Flg){
                         if(nivrow<=4){
                             ll.addView(iv, llp);
                             if(nivrow==4){
                                 rowFlg = false;
                                 row1Flg = false;
                                 nivrow = 0;
                                 gT.addView(ll);
                             }else if(niv == ImageNum2){
                                 gT.addView(ll);
                             }
                         }
                     }else if(rowFlg == false){
                         LinearLayout nll = new LinearLayout(FriendsDiaries.this);
                         LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                         nll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                         ll = nll;
                         rowFlg = true;
                         ll.addView(iv, lp);
                         if(niv == ImageNum2){
                             gT.addView(ll);
                         }
                     }else{
                         if(nivrow<=4){
                             ll.addView(iv,llp);
                             if(nivrow==4){
                                 rowFlg = false;
                                 nivrow = 0;
                                 gT.addView(ll);
                             }else if(niv == ImageNum2){
                                 gT.addView(ll);
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }else{
                     ll.addView(iv,llp);
                     Log.w("string", ""+niv);
                     if(niv == ImageNum2){
                         gT.addView(ll);
                         boolean test = true;
                         Log.i("string", ""+ test);
                     }
                 }

                 } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                    if(fFlg2){
                        startIdx2 += endIdx2+1;
                    }else{
                        startIdx2 = endIdx2+1;
                    }

                    fFlg2 = false;
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

I cannot find what is wrong with the code, any suggestions?

Comment: Is [this](http://i.imgur.com/nESl8.png) what you're going for?

Comment: I took this pictures as to show what I already achieve with this code. [example1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b19aargwvq3qzbg/1.png)  [example2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yy9hum1suj3pz7l/2.png)  [example3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dev3u1aq0crkwvb/3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I corrected the behavior dynamically generating all the cells as needed inside the same cycle that I use to decode the JSON array, I think my problem was caused by the recycling of the cells when using the list view widget, but I am not 100% sure about that, if anyone could confirm it.

What I would like to know is  if from the performance point of view is there a big difference with my approach against using the list view widget?